# FileReader "Error ProgressEvent" на больших файлах

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webbrowser

При загрузке больших файлов (4+ Gb),файлы открываются через стандартную функцию

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

в консоли браузера вываливается ошибка

```
Error ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 0, total: 6777708138, type: "error"…}
```

Можно ли как то это обойти.
Это нужно для подсчёта хэша файла, или может есть ещё какой-то способ получить уникальный id загружаемого файла в браузере.

Comment: я думаю вы привысили лимит http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

Answer (score 0):

Хром 56 читает примерно до 3Gb, потом вываливается с ошибкой браузера "Сhrome не хватает памяти".
При попытке загрузить файлы 8-200Gb сразу вываливается ошибка `ProgressEvent`.

---

Очевидно, что хром оберегает память (ха!) и не даёт её убить всю.
Можно считать произвольные 1-2Gb из файла и хэшировать их:

```js
let inp   = document.querySelector('input'),
    fr    = new FileReader(),
    chunk = 100; // 100bytes
    
inp.addEventListener('change', _ => {
  // Если выбранный файл меньше чанка,
  // берём всё, иначе отрезаем кусочек у начала по размеру чанка
  let blob = inp.files[0].size <= chunk ? inp.files[0] : inp.files[0].slice(0, chunk);
  
  fr.onloadend = _ => {
    let chunkOfFile = fr.result;
    console.info(chunkOfFile);
  };

  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
});
```

```html
<input type='file' />
```

---

Работа с такими файлами в браузере - дело странное, подумайте об альтернативных путях.

Comment: Я уже тоже к этому склоняюсь, осталось понять есть ли какая-то встроенная в браузер функция подсчёта хэша на стороне клиента, ибо "имя файла + размер" не дают 100% уверенности в совпадении файла сервера с локальным файлом.

Comment: @vnn198, ещё веб не дошёл до такой стадии, где необходима работа с ФС и вытекающими типа идентификации файла. Но мы на рубеже :)